# Can I attach a water softener drain to my gutter drain?

Tags: water-softener

I'm installing a water softener drain in the garage and I'm wondering if it would be okay to have it drain to a gutter drain by drilling a hole out of my garage? The gutter drain is connected to a French drain that would put the water out onto the street. Anything wrong with that? Who do I need to contact for permission to do that?

Comment: You cannot dump graywater into the storm sewer (_your local waterways_) in any modern jurisdiction nor with any moral standing. Don't. Please.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Broadly speaking, most drains are either sewage or storm. Storm for the outside - gutters, runoff, etc. Sewage for the inside - toilets, sinks, dishwashers, laundry, tubs/showers, etc. Generally speaking water that is dirty in a *human* way (i.e., not just dirty because it ran down a muddy hill) is not allowed to go into the storm drain. It needs to be processed - either actively via the municipal sewage treatments system or passively with a septic tank/leach field.

A quick look at a Rheem water softener from Home Depot says this in the installation manual (repeated a couple of times in different ways):

> Use a floor drain, laundry tub, sump, standpipe, or other options (check your local codes).

"local codes" is the key. If your area specifically *allows* water softener drains to go to the storm sewer system then you can run it outside with the gutter. Otherwise the clear default is to go to a house drain of some sort and out to the sewage system.

Comment: Does anyone, anywhere, treat water passing through the storm sewer? If not, this is just a terrible idea. Full stop.

Comment: @isherwood  I am not sure of the mechanics of the systems, but a few places do have problems with having to dump untreated sewage into rivers during rain storms.

Comment: @crip659 There were some issues of that type in Washington, DC until (I think) they added some more very large holding areas of some type. It might have been (but not sure and don't feel like researching it now) that *all* sewage and storm went together and was *all* treated, but in large storms that was just too much and so the *mix* would get sent out untreated, which is not a good thing.

Comment: That's the typical case with the older style combined sewage and storm sewer systems. When built they just dumped into the river or sea, tough luck being downstream. They eventually got treatment, but separating the flows in old built-up areas is not easy nor cheap, so the combined flow got treatment, but large storm flow overwhelms the containment. It's one reason that things which slow the rate of runoff have been encouraged or required.

Comment: Indeed, many older cities have one set of pipes that take both sewer and storm water. My brother in Boston has that issue where the drain from the roof (4 story building) can cause backflow in 1st floor toilets. Digging up every street in Boston to run new pipes would be ... difficult.